# How can I make my controller catch the data submitted by a form from one of his views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search

So basically I want to make search functionality in ASP.NET MVC. I am currently trying to retrieve data from a form as a string and print it to ensure that it gets the correct information. My view and controller are:

View:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <form method="post" asp-controller="MainPage" asp-action="Search" id="form1">
        <label for="licensePlate">Enter license plate:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="License Plate" name="licensePlate" id="licensePlate" />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class MainPageController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<MainPageController> _logger;
    private readonly UnblockMeContext _dbContext;

    public MainPageController(ILogger<MainPageController> logger,UnblockMeContext appData)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _dbContext = appData;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = _dbContext.Users.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }

    public IActionResult Search(string result)
    {         
        return Content(result);
    }
}
```

When I press on search button to submit the form a blank page appears but I want to print out the string that was submitted.

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the controller search action method parameter name to match with the FORM NAME.

```
public IActionResult Search(string licensePlate = "")
{         
    return Content(licensePlate);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain with do I have to do this?

Comment: Because you are sending `licensePlate` to the server but your controller action accept `result`.